# Intent not working properly in switch between different activities

Tags: android, android-intent, toggle, togglebutton

I have made an application with 5 activities-calculator1.java,calculator2.java,deposit.java,calculator3.java,calculator4.java respectively,In activity 1 there is a toggle button and a next button,and all the other activities contains a next button,Now i want is when toggle button is pressed and next button pressed then it should goto calculator2.java,and from calculator2.java,when i press next button,if the "toggleButton" of calculator.java is "on" it should go to deposit.java else go to calculator3.java,

**My code is as below:(on next button click):**

**Calculator1.java**

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this, Calculator2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", tg.isChecked());
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**Calculator2.java**

```
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             final boolean val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("tg");
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(val==true){
                        Intent iq=new Intent(Calculator2.this,Deposit.class);
                        startActivity(iq);
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent ir= new Intent(Calculator2.this,Calculator_3Activity.class);
                        startActivity(ir);
                    }

            }
        });
```

**Deposit.java**

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Intent iy = new Intent(Deposit.this,Calculator_3Activity.class);
startActivity(iy);

    }
});
```

**Calculator3.java**

```
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // final boolean  val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("tg");
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i1=new Intent(Calculator_3Activity.this ,Calculator_4Activity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                //finish();
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: and the problem is ? (apart from the obvious "tg" != "toggleBtn" ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Calculator1.java** has

```
intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", tg.isChecked());
```

in  **Calculator2.java**

```
final boolean val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("toggleBtn");
```

instead of `final boolean val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("tg");`

Answer (score 2):

**Calculator1.java**

```
btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent intent = new Intent(Calculator_1Activity.this, Calculator2.class);
                intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", tg.isChecked());
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Calculator3.java**

```
final boolean val= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean(**"toggleBtn"**);
```

Comment: how can it possible to get Intent in calculator3.java when you pass intent from calculator1.java to calculator2.java?

Comment: den u also send Intent intent = new Intent(Calculator_2Activity.this, Calculator3.class);
                intent.putExtra("toggleBtn", tg.isChecked());
                startActivity(intent);