# how to pass the selected value to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

Im new to android..

Im facing problem with intent..

My problem is...I want pass the user selected value from string arrayList of one activity to another activity...The values are string..got from database through JSON. And the values are stored in a arraylist..

Now i need to pass the value from one activity to another..by using intent..

> ```
>       lvForDialog = (ListView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.List_view);
>         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(Nexttopic.this, R.layout.row_topic, R.id.child_row,tnamelist));
>         lvForDialog.setAdapter(adapter);        
>         lvForDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
>     {
>              @Override
>              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)        
>           {            
>         Intent intent = new Intent(Nexttopic.this,Question.class);     
>     intent.putExtra(TAG_TOPICNAME, tname);
> ```

I want to pass the `TAG_TOPICNAME` to another activity..Which topic name the user selects that name i want to pass...

How to do this?

thanks a lot..

Comment: You have to see this link:-

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705964/intent-not-working-properly-in-switch-between-different-activities/14706046#14706046>

Comment: @hcd thats for button...i need for onItemclickListener...

Comment: Thanks to all..for answer to my question..and guide me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
i.putExtra("Name", tname );
startActivity(i);
```

in your first Activity and then you can add code below to your second Activity and get your data.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Name = intent.getExtras().getString("Name");
```

**Edit:** Use This as an Example to get selected item in onitemclick Listener

```
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
{ 
    Cursor GettName = (Cursor)viewList.getItemAtPosition(position);//Get a Cursor from the selected position to access the selected Item
    String tname = GettName.getString(GettName.getColumnIndex(CustomerDBAdapter.KEY_TNAME)); // get approporiate String from that cursor
    i.putExtra("Name", tname );
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What user selects that value should pass

Comment: for example in a listview when user click on a list item you should take selecteditem with implementing onitemclick listener then you can use it to pass to the second Activity.it's not defferent in other implementations, here tname is a string so you just have to fill it with user selected item

Comment: like that only i wrote in onitemclick listener see my code..what ever the user selects its passing the first value alone..not selected value..

Comment: look at an example in my edited answer hope it gave you the idea.Good Luck

Comment: How to implement your code i cant understand? im new to android..please guide me..

Comment: if you don't know something ask what didn't you understand and look for it on StackOverFlow and google you will find something useful.we can't post long comment here so i gave you the idea that how you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

you should call `startActivity(learnintent);` which is missing in your code after below lines

```
Intent learnintent = new Intent(Nexttopic.this,Question.class);     
learnintent.putExtra(TAG_TOPICNAME, tname);
```

i hope you also defined constant `TAG_TOPICNAME` before using it.

then in `Question` activity do something like below to access the value.

```
String topicName = intent.getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_TOPICNAME);
```

here `TAG_TOPICNAME` should be the same value i assigned in previous activity, better define a `class Constants` and put this String constant there, and use it at both places.

Comment: no, i didnt get..i want what user selects that value i should pass...please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the values by using a bundles.You can bundle it and pass it with the intent.A sample code is shown below....

bundle = new Bundle();
        data1 = Double.valueOf(myEditText.getText().toString());

```
    bundle.putDouble("data1", data1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

example of getting it form the intent

```
 Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        noqs = b.getDouble("data1");
        mTvCat.setText("hhhhhh"+point+noqs);
```

And also if its okey for you then you can store it in a static variable. And you can access it from any point of the application.

Comment: What is the type of the value???You can store it in a constant  value. I think this will help because if you store it in a constant value you need not pass it via bundle also you can directly call it from other activity using class name.